# Поиск окна html

Tags: html, javascript

Помогите, если это возможно. Вот открываю окно

```
myWindow=parent.window.open(бла,бла)
```

Отправляю в него команду `myWindow.команда` - все работает, но когда перезагружаю страницу, с которой было открыто окно, то команда больше не выполняется, пока снова не кликну на `parent.window.open`.

Суть вопроса: можно ли сделать так, что после перезагрузки страницы, с которой было открыто окно, при нажатии на кнопку с командой происходила бы функция поиска окна по названию или еще как-либо и если такое есть, то фокусировалось бы на нем и потом передавало команду именно в него, не перезагружая само окно, в которое нужно передать команду.

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда, есть варианты. =)

```
window.onunload = function(){myWindow.close();}
```

Одним из них является установка метки в родительском окне и ее мониторинг из дочернего окна (`window.opener.getMetka()`). При изменении метки выполнять открытие окна заново. Все это делается с помощью `setTimeout()`, а метку можно ставить временнУю.

Comment: К сожалению пока с JavaScriptом на вы и стоя, если Вас бы не затруднило написать конкретно что куда и как ,буду благодарен , если нет что же значит не судьба.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript обновляется при каждой загрузке страницы, запомнить там не получиться. Если необходимо что то запомнить пишите в cookie и при загрузке страницы читайте их.

Comment: Что бы записать куки нужны знания Javascript , а их пока нет . Или я что то не так понимаю по поводу знаний Javascript .